# How do you get a python script to repeat x times over again?

Tags: python, selenium, loops

I need to run a python script 10 times over again, but the script always returns an intentional error at the end. This stops the script so I can't use a for or while loop to repeat the script. The error is there because there is a random number of questions that I have set on my website to come up, with a max of 7 questions. So I created a while loop to click a element 7 times, but if there is a smaller amount of questions generated it returns an error, that the element isn't found. So somehow I need help ignoring this error or be able to run the whole .py file over again 10 times, like restarting the script.

I've also tried using try/catch or except statements to ignore the error but it doesn't work.

Here is the section where the error comes up:

```
b = 6
i = 0
    try:
        while i < b:
            print("We're in")
            time.sleep(2)
            Pass_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-chat')
            Pass_box.click()
            try:
                Cool_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name(
'message-submit'
)
                Cool_box.click()
            except:
                print("")
            i = i + 1
            print(i)
        driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
        g = g + 1
    except IOError:
        driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
        g = g + 1
```

The g + 1, was used when I was trying to make a while loop.

Comment: Share the error you are getting

Comment: Try switching the `while` and `try` to that the `try` is inside the `while`. Handle as many as specific exceptions that you expect, and put a generic `except` at the end to catch missing ones. Log that unexpected exception so you are aware of it. At the end, use `finally `to do the `g = g + 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the answer. So instead of using a set number of times I repeat the loop (7), I used selenium to pull the number from my website. This way no error would ever come up. I also figured out another solution which was to just use a plain try/except statement (not include the IOError), but I didn't end up using this because if a actual error came up I wouldn't know. Thanks for the help nevertheless.

(Edit):
The code I used for pulling the numbers was

```
Numbers_Element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(“//a[@class=’Enter a class here’]”)
Number = Numbers_Element.text
Number_refined = int(filter(str.isdigit, Number))
```

Then I used number_refined in my loop:

```
While i < Number_refined:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried swaping the first *try* with your *while*? And adding a generic exception on your first *try*? This will prevent any execution error.

**Tip**: share your error on your question.

```py
b = 6
i = 0
    while i < b:
        try:
                print("We're in")
                time.sleep(2)
                Pass_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-chat')
                Pass_box.click()
                try:
                    Cool_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('message-submit')
                    Cool_box.click()
                except:
                    print("")
                i = i + 1
                print(i)
            driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
            g = g + 1
        except Exception:
            driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
            g = g + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the count of questions first in every time of loop.

```
questions_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('message-submit'))
                                        ^^
```

And like this:

```
while time < 10:
    questions_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('message-submit'))
    while i < questions_count:
        .......
```